# Set Windows event's UserData

Tags: powershell, winapi, get-winevent

I'm trying to simulate the creation of a certain Windows event using Powershell's New-WinEvent. The events that I try to mimic have the following top level structure in the Event Viewer's XML view:

```
<Event>
  <System>
    <!--ID, provider, etc-->
  </System>
  <UserData>
    <!-- Data specific to this particular event type-->
  </UserData>
</Event>
```

Now, the event that I create using the following line

```
New-WinEvent -ProviderName Microsoft-Windows-XXX -Id 999 -Payload @("Hello world")
```

using the same provider and ID, get the following XML instead:

```
<Event>
  <System>
    <!--ID, provider, etc-->
  </System>
  <EventData>
    <Data Name="EventWriteData">Hello world</Data>
  </EventData>
</Event>
```

So the payload goes into `EventData` instead of `UserData`. Is it possible to initialize the latter? If not via the New-WinEvent, maybe directly via .NET API (e. g. `System.Diagnostics.EventLog.WriteEvent()`)?

---

[The Event schema](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wes/eventschema-eventtype-complextype) says:

> Typically, this section will contain with the EventData or UserData section. The EventData section is used if the template does not contain a UserData section.

The event template, one assumes, is loaded from the provider's resource files. The cmdlet issues a warning that the data doesn't conform to the template if you provide, say, two strings as payload.

Using `ProviderMetadata`, I've pulled a template for that event by the ID. It goes:

```
<template xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events">
  <data name="EventWriteData" inType="win:UnicodeString" outType="win:Xml"/>
</template>
```

Which is extremely generic - string in, XML out. And there is nothing there that would suggest `UserData`.